# Using div style cannot make border display

Tags: html, css

I have this code on my WordPress site for a MailChimp optin, but for some reason the border all of a sudden disappeared, can you please see what I may be missing?

```html
<div style="border-style: solid thin #FFFFFF">
  <p style="float:left; padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;"><img src="http://www.xxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/photo.jpg" style="width:115px; height:auto;" class="border"></p>
  <p><text 
  </p> 
  &nbsp;

  <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
  <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/horizontal-slim-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup{background:#FFFFFF; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
    /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
  </style>
  <div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="//xxxxxxx.us14.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=2b24d9a7eb0e64eed113ca92c&amp;id=6444b29c17" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
      <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
        <label for="mce-EMAIL">Subscribe to our mailing list</label>
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="email address" required>
        <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_2b24d9a7eb0e64eed113ca92c_6444b29c17" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have a few errors in the code above, don't know if your original code has the same errors, might want to have a look at that

Answer (score 1):

Border style does not accept color, nor "thin" as a value.

You want to use "border" in the context you're attempting to:

```
<div style="border: solid thin #FFFFFF">
  hello
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4tm3d1jm/

Your div element might be overridden by other styles applying borders (or border: none) to all div elements in your document, though.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style?v=control

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<div style= 'border: 2px solid #fff'>
```

Instead of your div

I hope that:

```
#mc_embed_signup{background:#FFFFFF; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}
```

Is between style tags

```
<style>#mc_embed_signup{background:#FFFFFF; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%;}</style>
```

If not, it won't work. Styles have to be applied in a css file, or between tags. 
Additionally I want you to remember about css hierarchy ([CSS Selector Hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987293/css-selector-hierarchy))